# How to set initial width of NSSearchToolbarItem

Tags: appkit, macos-big-sur, nssearchfield, nssearchtoolbaritem

The default width of `NSSearchToolbarItem` is way too large. I want it to be similar to the Notes app.

*Is there an official way to do this?*

The control has a property `preferredWidthForSearchField`, but this has no effect, which could also be one of the many Big Sur bugs.

The classic but deprecated `minSize` and `maxSize` settings seems to work, but then the control loses the ability to automatically resize itself according the available toolbar space.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the best way, but this seems to work:

```
searchToolbarItem.searchField.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: searchToolbarItem.searchField, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .lessThanOrEqual, toItem: nil, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1, constant: 200) )
searchToolbarItem.searchField.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: searchToolbarItem.searchField, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .greaterThanOrEqual, toItem: nil, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1, constant: 30) )
```

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 5

Based on the already given answer.

```swift
let search = NSSearchToolbarItem()
search.searchField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
```